# How can i able to convert pdf, xlsx and doc file in base64 data in ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, ionic3

My code is:

```
addFilesforRNAppz(inputFile: any) {
 const fileget = this.fileInputVariable.nativeElement.files;

 let fileList: FileList = inputFile.target.files;

 // I can access the selected file name, size and object correctly without any issues
 console.log("File name = " + fileList[0].name);
 console.log("File size = " + fileList[0].size);
 console.log("File = " + fileList[0]);

 // Converting the file input to base 64 (This rarely works)
 this.convertFileToBase64AndSet(fileList);

 // ===============================================================
}
convertFileToBase64AndSet(fileList: FileList)
{
   if(fileList.length > 0)
  {
    var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = (e: Event) => {

      console.log(reader.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[0]);
  }
}


<input type="file" #inputFile (change)="addFilesforRNAppz($event)" class="file-input" />
```

I want base64 data of selected pdf or any doc file. I can be convert Image into base64, but it does not convert from pdf to base64 data.

what is the problem in my code, please give any solution as soon as possible, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I can be convert Image into base64, but it does not convert from pdf to base64 data.

Your *reading* code will work the same for `img` or `pdf` or anything else. However I suspect you are trying to use the read value as a `data-uri` `src`. That will not work for `pdf` files and will only work for images.

Comment: Yes I am getting same issues. I am also not able to convert pdf or any doc file. so is there any other functions or any other code which work for pdf or doc? @basarat

Comment: If you have any other suggestion then please let me know. thanks :)

Comment: so, what is the solution to convert pdf into base64 data?

Answer (score 0):

To convert pdf you can use :

```
file.readAsArrayBuffer(filePath, fileName)
```

Following is the complete code for reading pdf which is got by filechooser plugin:

```
this.fileChooser.open().then((uri) => {
       this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri).then((finalUri) => {
         this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(finalUri).then((entry) => {
          let filePath = entry.nativeURL.substring(0, entry.nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/'));
          if (entry.name.endsWith('.pdf')){
            return this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(filePath, entry.name)
              .then((data) => {
                //data after reading pdf
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                //error
              });
          }
        })
      })
    })
```

Comment: Hello @Shrutika Patil, I tried your solution, but getting error **FileError
code:13,message:"input is not a directory"**

Comment: Can you please read the documentation of readAsArrayBuffer to know the required format for file path ? You will need to use file plugin first then you will get a uri of file , then after converting it into local file system you will get a path

Comment: I have edited my answer and provided complete code which is working in my project. Please try it.